# How to convert Item list to List<Item> in F#

Tags: f#

Trying to do something pretty basic - convert an F# List to a .Net Generic list ( I think )

I am new to F#.

```
let items = 
    pricelistItems    // List<PriceListItem>
    |> Seq.map(fun pli -> 
        let item = 
            new Item(
                Code = pli.sku,
                Description = "",
                IsPurchased = true,
                IsSold = true,
                IsTrackedAsInventory = true,
                InventoryAssetAccountCode = "xxxx"
            )
        item
    )
    |> Seq.toList
```

the resulting type of the code above is

```
Item list
```

I think this is an F# type?  I need to somehow get it it to be a

```
List<Item>
```

thanks for your time

Comment: Use `ResizeArray<'a>` which is defined as `type ResizeArray<'a> = System.Collections.Generic.List<'a>`. F# `List<'a>` is `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<'a>`. Sample `let lis = ResizeArray(Seq.map string [1; 2; 3])`

Comment: Just replace `|> Seq.ToList` with `|> ResizeArray`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to keep data in the `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`  collection?

Comment: @TomasPetricek it is a collection of types from a C# library ( Xero ) - so I need to push it back to that API in that format.

Comment: @AlbertoLeón  thank you.   I haven't tested it but it appears to accept it even though it's a slightly different type.  |> List<Item>  seems to work as well, I will test them both out.

Comment: Replace Seq.toList with List (see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the naming here is a bit confusing, because F# defines its own `List` type (which is an immutable list) and can be written as `List<'T>`, `'T List` or also `list<'T>` or `'T list`. These all refer to the F# list. To refer to the standard generic .NET type, F# uses `ResizeArray<'T>` or you can use fully qualified name of `System.Collections.Generic.List<'T>`

As mentioned in the comments, you can convert a sequence back into `ResizeArray` by using the constructor. However, the generic .NET list type also supports `map` operation directly, except that it is an instance method called `ConvertAll`. You could use that or write a more F#-friendly wrapper:

```
module ResizeArray = 
  let map f (l:ResizeArray<_>) = l.ConvertAll(System.Converter(f))
```

Then you can write:

```
let items = pricelistItems |> ResizeArray.map (fun pli ->
  Item(Code = pli.sku, 
       Description = "",
       IsPurchased = true,
       IsSold = true,
       IsTrackedAsInventory = true,
       InventoryAssetAccountCode = "xxxx") )
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert an F# list to a System.Collections.Generic.List use either **System.Linq.ToList** or simply the constructor **System.Collections.Generic.List**

```
open System.Linq
open System.Collections.Generic

let l = [1..3] // F# lists implement IEnumerable<'t>, so we can use

l.ToList()     // System.Linq.ToList method

l |> List      // System.Collections.Generic.List constructor
```

Your specific code is then

```
let items =
    pricelistItems    // List<PriceListItem>
    |> Seq.map(fun pli ->
        let item =
            new Item(
                Code = pli.sku,
                Description = "",
                IsPurchased = true,
                IsSold = true,
                IsTrackedAsInventory = true,
                InventoryAssetAccountCode = "xxxx"
            )
        item
    )
    |> System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList
```

You can also pass the sequence (which is IEnumerable<>) to the System.Collections.Generic.List constructor:

```
open System.Collections.Generic // List

let items =
    pricelistItems    // List<PriceListItem>
    |> Seq.map(fun pli ->
        let item =
            new Item(
                Code = pli.sku,
                Description = "",
                IsPurchased = true,
                IsSold = true,
                IsTrackedAsInventory = true,
                InventoryAssetAccountCode = "xxxx"
            )
        item
    )
    |> List   // constructor accepting IEnumerable = the sequence above
```

Note that "List" above is actually List you could also type List<_> and let the compiler infer the type or even insert your type. I prefer the shortest way and leave the generic out, which the compiler accepts. These are equivalent:

```
[1..3] |> List
[1..3] |> List<_>
[1..3] |> List<int>
```